# Как мне с помощью ajax делать запросы в цикле?

Tags: php, javascript

Приветствую. Задача в том чтобы каждое значение из массива `datalist` передать по очереди в цикле обработчику и дождаться результата прежде чем будет сделан следующий запрос. Дело в том что обработчик может обрабатывать запрос от 10 секунд до 2-3 минут и нужно обязательно дождаться результата обработки текущего значения из массива. 
В таком варианте скрипт не ждет пока придет результат, а по кругу быстро перебирает все значения:

```
var datalist = ['data1','data2','data3'];
var count = datalist.length;
var step;


for (step = 0; step <= count; step++) {
    $.ajax({
          url: 'response.php?action='+domlist[step],
          success: function(data) {
            $('.results').html(data);
          }

        });
}
```

Comment: зачем такое изуверство? ajax - от слова **асинхронный** ...... какой смысл вызывать **асинхронный** запрос в цикле? какое поведение ожидалось?

Comment: Просто делай синхронные вызовы